# When is the scroll event fired when a page is loading?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

If I go to a page with a hash tag, e.g http://www.wired.com/#spack4, I notice that the page loads and then jumps down to the id `spack4`. I'd like to attach a Javascript function for when it jumps down. Is there a DOM event that triggers this?

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do?

Maybe you could use the `window.pageYoffset` property to check if the document is or is not at the top:

```
function isTopOfPage() {
    var yPosition = window.pageYOffset;

    if(yPosition == 0) {
        //top of page
        return true;
    }
    else if(yPosition > 0) {
    // not at the top of the page
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can then call this function onload.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried this and locally it worked like a dream, but as soon as I pushed it remotely `isTopOfPage()` fired before that scroll event fired. i.e always returned `true`. I'll post an example later today.

Comment: You have a small typo here. Should be `window.pageYOffset` (the capitalization matters, at least in Chrome).

Comment: Well spotted.  Corrected (better late than never)